# Definite article or not in "after (the) deformation"?

Tags: word-usage, definite-article, zero-article

Is the word **the**, that sometimes is put after the word **after**, optional?

For example, what sentence is more appropriate? (A) or (B)?

> (A) **After** deformation, a point in the plane takes other position.
>   (B) **After the** deformation, a point in the plane takes other position.

Comment: The "the" doesn't belong to the "after", it belongs to the thing that comes after the "after". Whether it is necessary depends on what that thing is, and what you are trying to say.

Comment: At best the second example is not normal usage. However you might say "After the deformation *of the plane,* ..." or "After the deformation *occurred,*...". BTW, as a rule you should not mark an answer as accepted so quickly. See the meta topic [**Not so fast! (When should I accept my answer?)**](http://meta.ell.stackexchange.com/questions/1307/not-so-fast-when-should-i-accept-my-answer).

Comment: Did you make these sentences yourself, or do you have a link for them? It would be easier to explain if the sentence were expressed in natural English, and "a point in the plane takes **other** position" is not natural. Perhaps you mean **another** position?

Answer (score 0):

Sentence A—the one without *the* —would be understood by native speakers to imply that the point itself is what underwent the deformation. (That would cause semantic problems because mathematical points are zero dimensional. Having no spatial extent, they cannot undergo deformation.)

Sentence B, on the other hand, suggests that what underwent deformation is something other than the point. Something understood from context: the plane mentioned, some space in which the point is embedded, something like that.